# IIRF url rewriting with IIS 6

Tags: php, url-rewriting, iis-6, iirf

I want to rewrite this url:

> "www.mydomain.com/myproject/index.php?function=demo"

to

> 'www.mydomain.com/myproject/home/demo'

and I have this code in my iirf.ini file:

```
RewriteEngine on
StatusInquiry On  /iirfSatus
RewriteLog c:\Inetpub\
RewriteLogLevel 3
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^/myproject/home/(.*)$ /myproject/index.php?function=$1 [L]
```

I still get a 404 error when I surf to the second link, and I don't know why.
Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I'm confused: RewriteCond is apache, but you want an answer for IIS?

Comment: I use iirf to rewrite my urls, It uses the same syntax. iirf is an extension for IIS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem myself after another hour of searching the web:
The problem was that my Iirf.ini file was in the wrong folder.
It was in the wwwroot instead of my project folder.
It works fine now